# UITapGestureRecognizer makes certain fields unclickable

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm using a UITapGestureRecognizer on the lowest down view (self.view) to hide my keyboard.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapHandler = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleBackgroundTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapHandler];
```

And the handleBackGroundTap method simply does

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

And this code works fine on most of my views except for a couple

1. a view where i'm using a tableview populated with clickable items (it's a list of checkboxes really)
2. a view that uses a datepicker (the datepicker should open when you click the textfield)

On those two views said items become unresponsive: the checkboxes are unclickable (they don't mark or unmark when tapped) and the datepicker refuses to show.

My question is: why? And: are there any workarounds?

Note: if I don't add the gesture recognizer the fields work fine but not being able to dismiss the keyboard is rather annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so as I was looking around i happened to stumble across a solution (which is typical... Have been searching for days and the moment I post a question I find the solution)

In any case adding

```
[tapHandler setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

solved the issue

edit: I have to wait 2 days to accept this as the answer...